# Neo4J using REST best way to accomplish several transactions as one ACID transactions

Tags: neo4j

For those that are using REST via .NET what would be the best way to accomplish several transactions as one ACID transactions? For example:

Transactions as ONE:

1. Delete one Node
2. Delete all relationships for the deleted node
3. Delete all NODES linked to the deleted node via the relationship.
4. Delete the deleted NODES from all Indexes

If this is not possible with REST can we get some recommendations of alternatives in order to achieve full ACID compliance? Is JAVA the only possible option to accomplish the above set of transactions as one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j 2.0 is adding [remote transactions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/preview/rest-api-transactional.html%29%20for%20details) via REST, but it is not stable yet. Beyond that, there is no transactional support via REST that I'm aware of. To the best of my knowledge, only the Java API provides any sort of transaction mechanism right now that will give you what you need.

Comment: That's a dead link now.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a suitable substitute link. All I can find is [this blog post](http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/04/nodes-are-people-too.html).

Answer (score 1):

The general direction for Neo4j is away from REST, toward mutating Cypher. Each individual Cypher statement is already in a transaction. In Neo4j 2.0, you'll be able to use remote transactions (but only for Cypher calls).

The scenarios you've called out should largely be achievable today using Cypher, allowing you to complete them in one call. If not, you should raise the specific scenarios that aren't so that Cypher can be extended accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cypher with REST via .NET (or Java). http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html

An advantage is you can make your queries more data-driven (by keeping your Cypher statements as template files).